# Should I use grub legacy or grub2 for a dedicated grub partition?

Tags: grub2, grub-legacy

A while back I had my dual-boot system running Ubuntu 14.xx, and Windows 7 (x64).
I created a dedicated grub partition.
I recall having used grub legacy rather than grub2 because the tutorial I was using recommended using it.

Is there any reason today to still be using grub legacy?
I now have a multi-boot system with Ubuntu 18.04 installed on 2 partitions (I am going to remove one of them eventually), Windows 7 Ultimate x64, and Windows 10.

I want the dedicated grub partition so that I won't lose access to Ubuntu when I do something stupid with Windows - or Windows does something stupid itself...

Thanks for your help

FW

Comment: I did a grub partition back with XP & grub legacy. But now just have grub2 installed in Ubuntu. New systems in last 5 years use UEFI, so UEFI is the fallback boot of any system not bootable by grub. With grub partition you have to manually install grub & maintain grub.cfg. Also with Windows 10 you have the issue of grub not booting Windows when hibernated & fast boot setting is hibernation. With newer UEFI you can directly boot Windows when grub will not boot it.

Comment: Unfortunately, my computer (mainboard) is of 2012 vintage, and does not support booting UEFI.
I do reacll not being able to boot into Windows (from grub) if it was in hibernation.

Comment: Grub2 has lots of improvements. If you really want grub in a separate partition you can do it. The format of grub.cfg is different than the old grub menu.lst. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have to do my homework before doing this, as I have a bad habit of diving into things without fully understanding them. The results are often unbootable OS's.